# GROUP BY with Count > Certain_Number

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, where-clause

My Table:

```
City   |   Country
--------------------
City1  |   Country1
City2  |   Country1
City3  |   Country1
City4  |   Country1
City1  |   Country2
City2  |   Country2
```

I want to select those countries that have less than 3 cities:

```
Count   |   Country
--------------------
2       |   Country2
```

So, my query is:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM Table GROUP BY Country WHERE Table.Count < 3
```

is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate expression in the `where` clause (this clause is processed before the aggregation actually happens). Instead, you can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY country 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As Count is not a column in your table,you cannot define as *Table.Count* instead you can give the alias name.
**WHERE** clause apply conditions for column. 
**HAVING** clause apply condition for aggregate function and can be used only after group by

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM Table GROUP BY Country HAVING Count < 3
```